# achieve stack smashing with executable file

Tags: c, buffer-overflow, stack-smash

I try to achieve stack smashing when I have only the executable file .
I use the objdump to get the assembly code for this source code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void func(char *str) { 
char buffer[24]; 
int *ret; 
strcpy(buffer,str); 
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
int x; 
x = 0; 
func(argv[1]); 
x = 1; 
printf("%d\n”,x); 
}
```

at run time ./a,out (value)....I need to insert the (value ) in such away I insert the NOP in stack location and that last part of (value) is the address of my next instruction.
I have 40 byte before reaching the location that contain the return address of the fun() .

```
08048444 <func>:
8048444:    55                      push   %ebp
8048445:    89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
8048447:    83 ec 48                sub    $0x48,%esp
804844a:    8b 45 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
804844d:    89 45 d4                mov    %eax,-0x2c(%ebp)
8048450:    65 a1 14 00 00 00       mov    %gs:0x14,%eax
8048456:    89 45 f4                mov    %eax,-0xc(%ebp)
8048459:    31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
804845b:    8b 45 d4                mov    -0x2c(%ebp),%eax
804845e:    89 44 24 04             mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
8048462:    8d 45 dc                lea    -0x24(%ebp),%eax
8048465:    89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
8048468:    e8 eb fe ff ff          call   8048358 <strcpy@plt>
804846d:    8b 45 f4                mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
8048470:    65 33 05 14 00 00 00    xor    %gs:0x14,%eax
8048477:    74 05                   je     804847e <func+0x3a>
8048479:    e8 fa fe ff ff          call   8048378 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
804847e:    c9                      leave  
804847f:    c3                      ret    

08048480 <main>:
8048480:    55                      push   %ebp
8048481:    89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
8048483:    83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
8048486:    83 ec 20                sub    $0x20,%esp
8048489:    c7 44 24 1c 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,0x1c(%esp)
8048490:    00 
8048491:    8b 45 0c                mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
8048494:    83 c0 04                add    $0x4,%eax
8048497:    8b 00                   mov    (%eax),%eax
8048499:    89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
804849c:    e8 a3 ff ff ff          call   8048444 <func>
80484a1:    c7 44 24 1c 01 00 00    movl   $0x1,0x1c(%esp)
80484a8:    00 
80484a9:    b8 90 85 04 08          mov    $0x8048590,%eax
80484ae:    8b 54 24 1c             mov    0x1c(%esp),%edx
80484b2:    89 54 24 04             mov    %edx,0x4(%esp)
80484b6:    89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
80484b9:    e8 aa fe ff ff          call   8048368 <printf@plt>
80484be:    b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
80484c3:    c9                      leave  
80484c4:    c3                      ret    
80484c5:    90                      nop
80484c6:    90                      nop
```

problem if I insert 00 its consider as (31) ASCII .How I can insert hex values.

... I hope the Que is clear

objdump -w -Mintel :

```
08048444 <func>:
8048444:    55                      push   ebp
8048445:    89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
8048447:    83 ec 48                sub    esp,0x48
804844a:    8b 45 08                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
804844d:    89 45 d4                mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x2c],eax
8048450:    65 a1 14 00 00 00       mov    eax,gs:0x14
8048456:    89 45 f4                mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc],eax
8048459:    31 c0                   xor    eax,eax
804845b:    8b 45 d4                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x2c]
804845e:    89 44 24 04             mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x4],eax
8048462:    8d 45 dc                lea    eax,[ebp-0x24]
8048465:    89 04 24                mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax
8048468:    e8 eb fe ff ff          call   8048358 <strcpy@plt>
804846d:    8b 45 f4                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc]
8048470:    65 33 05 14 00 00 00    xor    eax,DWORD PTR gs:0x14
8048477:    74 05                   je     804847e <func+0x3a>
8048479:    e8 fa fe ff ff          call   8048378 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
804847e:    c9                      leave  
804847f:    c3                      ret    

08048480 <main>:
8048480:    55                      push   ebp
8048481:    89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
8048483:    83 e4 f0                and    esp,0xfffffff0
8048486:    83 ec 20                sub    esp,0x20
8048489:    c7 44 24 1c 00 00 00 00     mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x1c],0x0
8048491:    8b 45 0c                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]

8048494:    83 c0 04                add    eax,0x4
8048497:    8b 00                   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [eax]
8048499:    89 04 24                mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax
804849c:    e8 a3 ff ff ff          call   8048444 <func>
80484a1:    c7 44 24 1c 01 00 00 00     mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x1c],0x1
80484a9:    b8 90 85 04 08          mov    eax,0x8048590
80484ae:    8b 54 24 1c             mov    edx,DWORD PTR [esp+0x1c]
80484b2:    89 54 24 04             mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x4],edx
80484b6:    89 04 24                mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax
80484b9:    e8 aa fe ff ff          call   8048368 <printf@plt>
80484be:    b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0`
```

Comment: What tool are you using to edit the binary file?

Comment: (Could you use `objdump -w -Mintel`? For my eyes' sake?)

Comment: No, he's studying stash smashing. Also he's not editing the binary file, he's just using `objdump` to get the assembly.

Comment: no I am not ... :P 
I am not editing any thing only relay on the value from CLI at run time

Comment: How are you inserting the value 00 (or trying to…)?

Comment: i need to insert \0 char so it consider as NOP

Answer (score 1):

You could use `./a.out $(perl -e "print '\x97';")` and replace \x97 by the hex you want to use.

Comment: perl ?? 
I can use it with more then one char >

Comment: @Haboosh You can, by putting more \x00 after the first one. Perl is __the__ most used tool to write shellcodes.

Comment: i did the following : 
I repeat the "print '\x00';" six times and the code work fine pushing the seventh give me error "stack smash" ... it indicate i am in location where ret addr is stored right ?

Answer (score 1):

If C, the end of string character is `0x00` (or `'\0'` if you prefer). So if you make your string exactly 39 characters long, then the 40th character will be the zero - and it will be in exactly the right place. There is no way to copy more than one zero in a C string - unless you use a function other than `strcpy` (for example, `memcpy`). But if you are relying on the `argv[1]` to be the source of your zero, then this is the only way. You could of course subtract something from the string before processing it - if you want, you could do

```
L = strlen(argv[1]);
for(int ii = 0; ii < L; ii++) if(argv[1][ii] == '0') argv[1][ii] = '\0';
```

This would turn every `'0'` into `'\0'`. But then you can't do a simple `strcpy`, you would have to do `memcpy`.

And you have to hope that you don't get a segfault for writing to memory you don't own…

Comment: Then you need a string of exactly 39 characters as your argument, and you will write a `nul` to the 40th location.

Comment: I think about it before but is there any chance to consider null as normal string cuz I deal with char * argv